# php.ini Timezone is not working - Laragon local development

Tags: php, timezone, laragon

I tried several times changing the timezone on php.ini, but for some reason timezone of my app installation is not picking it up. I've attached both app error and current php settings.

I am newbie, and spent the whole day trying to fix this, but still couldn't. Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image: Screenshot]

What am I missing here? Is it a problem with the app or Laragon?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi.  Please don't post a screenshot, but rather include the relevant part of the file as text in the question.  That said, it looks like you still have the time zone line commented out. (Remove the `;` at the front.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you removed the semicolon at the beginning of the line? If not, you should.

Comment: Yup! That was the issue! Such a shame i missed that all this time! Thanks alot mate!  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

find date.timezone in php.ini
set time zone as per your
date.timezone="Asia/Kolkata"